# How to make your graph wider in Dot?

Tags: dot

I have a simple graph created with dot which represents simple neural network.
[image: Simple graph generated with dot.]

I want to make this graph wider, i.e. make more space between layers by elongating edges. I tried to do it with `size` and `ratio` attributes but without success. Ratio works for height, but I want to increase width.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs this later, I have solved my problem with variable `ranksep`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `nodesep` variable?

[GraphViz documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:nodesep)

From the documentation it says "In dot, this specifies the minimum space between two adjacent nodes in the same rank, in inches."  So depending on how you have your ranks set up, this might help you.  The the look of your graph (lacking the .gv file), I'd guess that you're using invisible top-to-bottom ranks to align the vertical columns.  If this, the `nodesep` variable may work well for you.  The default is quite small, 0.25 inch.

Comment: I am already using `nodesep` and it regulates space between nodes in vertical direction. This is my [code](https://pastebin.com/jLA5k6r8). Is it possible to modify it so that it regulates horizontal space, and if so, how?